# Local storage in iphone using firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, storage, local

Is there a way where I can use firebase to store data on the iphone device so that even after the user turns off and then turns on the device, the data remains in the device?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your AppDelegate file

Swift 3

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FIRApp.configure()
    FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true

    return true
}
```